# Error with regular expression in R data frame

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I need to spread (unpivot) this `Customer` data frame:

```
                                                                  Value
Customer.CustomerID                                            21110001
Customer.AccountID                                             21110001
Customer.CustomerTaxID                                        123123123
Customer.CompanyName                                              S LDA
Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail                      Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.City                               Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode                         Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.Country                                      PT
Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail                       Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.City                                Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.PostalCode                          Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.Country                                       PT
Customer.SelfBillingIndicator                                         0
Customer.CustomerID.1                                          21110002
Customer.AccountID.1                                           21110002
Customer.CustomerTaxID.1                                      321321321
Customer.CompanyName.1                                             RLDA
Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail.1                    Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.City.1                             Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode.1                       Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.Country.1                                    PT
Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail.1                     Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.City.1                              Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.PostalCode.1                        Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.Country.1                                     PT
Customer.SelfBillingIndicator.1                                       0
Customer.CustomerID.2                                          21110004
Customer.AccountID.2                                           21110004
Customer.CustomerTaxID.2                                      999999999
Customer.CompanyName.2                                             RTDA
Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail.2                    Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.City.2                             Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode.2                       Desconhecido
Customer.BillingAddress.Country.2                                    PT
Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail.2                     Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.City.2                              Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.PostalCode.2                        Desconhecido
Customer.ShipToAddress.Country.2                                     PT
Customer.SelfBillingIndicator.2                                       0
```

I'm trying:

```
Customer <- Customer %>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  transmute(mycols = gsub('^.*\\.', '', gsub('.[[:digit:]]+', '', rowname)),
            numlinha = regmatches(rowname, gregexpr('[0-9]+',rowname)),
            value = Value) %>% 
  spread(key=mycols, value=value)
```

This is returning the error:

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (5, 9)
```

I think it is because the regular expression in `gsub` isn't dealing well with the row names `Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail` and `Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail` as the error message indicates.

The desired output would be a data frame where `CustomerID`, `AccountID`, `BillingAddress_Detail`,`ShipToAddress_Detail` etc. would be the column names.

However I've been sratching my head for hours to find a better regex, I just can't seem to find it. Help anyone?

EDIT: 
@Ronak Shah, this is the result I'm getting:
The first row is offset by one column.

[image]

Comment: Note that `.` in `.[[:digit:]]+` matches any char, not just a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier to help if you could have data for at least 2 customers. Anyway, I have created a sample of data for 2 of them based on my understanding. Since there are multiple customers and there couldn't be duplicate rownames in a dataframe I am assuming that there would be a leading digit in the rownames. We can remove them using `gsub`, create an identifier row for `spread`. Here I have assumed based on sample data shown that you have 10 fields for each Customer, if you have more or less than change the `each` argument in `rep` accordingly.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = gsub("Customer\\.|\\.\\d+$", "", rowname),  
         spread_row = rep(seq_len(n()), each = 10, length.out = n())) %>%
  spread(rowname, Value)

#  spread_row AccountID BillingAddress.AddressDetail BillingAddress.City BillingAddress.Country
#1          1  21110001                 Desconhecido        Desconhecido                    ZPT
#2          2  21110001            Desconhecidorobes        Desconhecido                    ZPT

#  BillingAddress.PostalCode CompanyName CustomerID CustomerTaxID ShipToAddress.AddressDetail ShipToAddress.City
#1              Desconhecido         SLD   21110001     123123123                Desconhecido       Desconhecido
#2              Desconhecido         SLD   21110002     123123123                Desconhecido       Desconhecido
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Value = c("21110001", "21110001", "123123123", 
"SLD", "Desconhecido", "Desconhecido", "Desconhecido", "ZPT", 
"Desconhecido", "Desconhecido", "21110002", "21110001", "123123123", 
"SLD", "Desconhecidorobes", "Desconhecido", "Desconhecido", "ZPT", 
"Desconhecido", "Desconhecido")), row.names = c("Customer.CustomerID", 
"Customer.AccountID", "Customer.CustomerTaxID", "Customer.CompanyName", 
"Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail", "Customer.BillingAddress.City", 
"Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode", "Customer.BillingAddress.Country", 
"Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail", "Customer.ShipToAddress.City", 
"Customer.CustomerID1", "Customer.AccountID1", "Customer.CustomerTaxID1", 
"Customer.CompanyName1", "Customer.BillingAddress.AddressDetail1", 
"Customer.BillingAddress.City1", "Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode1", 
"Customer.BillingAddress.Country1", "Customer.ShipToAddress.AddressDetail1", 
"Customer.ShipToAddress.City1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping, I have updated my question above. There are 13 fields for each customer, so I've updated your code. There's a problem with the first row: it is offset by a column (see picture above to get the idea). :-)

Comment: @NunoNogueira okay..it needed a small change in regex of `gsub`. I have updated it now. Can you check ?

Comment: wow, thank you, it is working now! And how about if the number of fields was variable? Is there a way to check each Customer.CustomerID and count the number of fields per each customer (leaving the blanks as NA)?

Comment: If the number of fields is variable maybe you could do `unique(diff(which(grepl("Customer.CustomerID", rownames(df)))))`